# Where is Nobutsuna Kamiizumi and Alternis Dim in Chapter 5

Tags: bravely-default

In Chapter 5 after getting the party together and getting back onto Grandship a whole bunch of sidequests open up, all of which are re-fighting Eternia's Asterisk Holders.

So far i just beaten Lord DeRosso, the last one i had marked on the map however i haven't re-fought Swordmaster Nobutsuna Kamiizumi, Pirate Capatin Hayreddin Barbarossa and Dark Knight Alternis Dim and thewre are no more side quest markers on the map.

i know i won't be able to fight Barbarossa until i release the Water Crystal so i can land the ship in the water and sail to the fog bank however Kamiizumi was at the Swordbearers' H.Q, Starkfort, however i went there and he wasn't there. considering that in the world Chapter 5 is in

> Olivia died in an earthquake months before rather than being killed by Victoria

i thought maybe Kamiizumi was somewhere else so i fought Dr Quda however, just like last time how he fakes his death Kamiizumi turns up while he is plotting and slays him, however there's no subquest marker on Starkfort like there was when Dr Quda was there (so that rules out him only being available after Quda is dead).

So i am wondering, where do i re-fight Swordmaster Nobutsuna Kamiizumi? or is he a storyline boss like what some of the Asterisk Holders were the first time (is so don't spoil it).

I'm also asking the same for Alternis Dim however i got a feeling that he was still alive when what ever happened at the Pillar of Light occurred and proable is a storyline boss like he was in the previous chapter, but i want to double check as not to miss out on a sidequest fight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swordmaster Nobutsuna Kamiizumi becomes available after awakening the Fire Crystal however am unsure if Braev the Templar needed to be defeated and learning of his past with Kamiizumi and how they both loved Mahzer (only learned that in Chapter 5) are also requirements as during the cutscene Kamiizumi commented on how Edea had already defeated her father and Edea commented lot on Kamiizumi's past with her mother and father.

while that's the same way he became available in Chapter 3 and should have have been logical, Time Mage Eloch Quentis Khamer VIII and Spell Fencer Ciggma Khint only became available after the Wind Crystal was awakened in Chapter 1 but in Chapter 5 they could be fought before then.

As i suspected Pirate Captain Hayreddin Barbarossa was available after the Water Crystal was awakened as the sub-quest marker appeared at the shack where the sub-quest begins.

Dark Knight Alternis Dim is still a Storyline Boss so unlike the other Storyline Bosses  he isn't optional.